# How to add another subcolumn to dataframe with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to add a third column "Productivity" so every role like Admin would have three sub columns produktiv, unproduktiv and Productivity.

Productivity would be calculated as follows:

Productivity = Produktiv / (Produktiv + Unproduktiv) * 100

[image: dataframe]
(don't mind the s, I had to anonymize the data)

Here is the output of df.columns

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only `Produktiv` and `Unproduktiv` level for `sum` is possible aggregate by first level of `MultiIndex`, divide by `Produktiv` and after `rename` second level of `MultiIndex` append to originam Dataframe by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = (df.xs('Produktiv', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)
         .div(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum(), level=0).mul(100))

df = (pd.concat([df, df1.rename(columns={'Produktiv':'Productivity'}, level=1)], axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .reindex(['Produktiv','Unproduktiv','Productivity'], level=1, axis=1))
print (df)
```

Another idea is get both slices by `Produktiv, Unproduktiv` and add level by `pd.concat` first:

```
df1 = df.xs('Produktiv', axis=1, level=1)
df2 = df.xs('Unproduktiv', axis=1, level=1)

df11 = (pd.concat({'Productivity':df1.div(df1.add(df2)).mul(100)}, axis=1)
          .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1))
    
df = (pd.concat([df, df11], axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .reindex(['Produktiv','Unproduktiv','Productivity'], level=1, axis=1))
```